# Invalid use of auto when declaring a variable C++, C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Whenever I try to compile my code I get an invalid use of auto. Coming from a Java background, I am not sure if I quite understand  C++ templates. It seems like the compiler can infer the type. I am limited to C++11.

The error occurs in the GeneralRenderer.

**Animal classes**

```
class Animal {};

class Dog : public Animal {};

class Cat : public Animal {};

enum AnimalType {
    Dog,
    Cat
};
```

**Render Classes**

```
template<class T>
class AnimalRenderer {
    virtual void draw(T entity) = 0;
};

class DogRenderer : public AnimalRenderer<Dog> {};


class CatRenderer : public AnimalRenderer<Cat> {};
```

**Logic**

```
class GeneralRenderer {
public:
    void draw(
            std::map<AnimalType, std::vector<Animal>> animalMap) {

        for (auto entry: animalMap) { 
            AnimalRenderer<auto> renderer; // <--- Causes the error
            switch (entry.first) {
                case Dog:
                    renderer = DogRenderer();
                    break;
                case Cat:
                    renderer = CatRenderer();
                    break;
            }

            for (auto animal: entry.second) {
                renderer.draw(entry);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Nevermind that the syntax is wrong, how should the compiler deduce the type? It has no information when you define `renderer` to deduce the right type.

Comment: I think the difference in understanding is that auto is limited in c++ to doing static - compile-time decisions. It does not mean automatic/variant.

Comment: The thing to know is C++ favors compile-time behaviors.  So in Java something can hang around like that auto and wait to resolve until later, but in C++ it has to resolve at compile time - therefore it fails, as Bathsheba says, because it doesn't have the information it needs

Comment: Thanks you for the answers, I understand now. Is there a way around this?

Comment: you don't even need declare animalRender as template, since you're using it like an interface. Removing it and <auto> make your program legal.

Comment: thus, using an enum to do an allocation by switch make that structure not useful at all. It seems you're just using concept like auto, template etc just to use it, am I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Informally speaking, `auto` can be used to declare and initialise a type at the same time. Then the compiler can infer the type from the value used to initialise the variable.

But that's not the case here; a statement like

```
auto n;
```

will fail similarly.

Note that `auto` merely stands in for a type that is *known at compile time*. It's there to make code more readable although its use is occasionally obligatory such as when working with lambda functions. It is *not* a variant-type construct cf. `std::variant` say of C++17.

Finally note that a `std::map` is a very different beast to a `java.util.Map`. There's no *type erasure* in C++ so a `std::map<A, B>` is a fundamentally different type to a `std::map<C, D>` if `A` is a different type to `C` and / or `B` differs from `D`. Furthermore, C++ allows you to store value types in maps.

Answer (score 1):

As the other users already say, auto can‘t work without a righthand variable.

I think you should remove the template annotation from AnimalRenderer, then you can use the classes normally.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result you want you effectively need to move the second for-loop inside the cases, where the deduction can be resolved for each case.

You don't want code duplication, so ideally you want a template function you can call to do the second loop. On the latest c++ standards you might also be able to declare a template lambda function.

That said, architecturally, I would suggest adding an interface base class for AnimalRenderer, and then you can declare a simple pointer to that base class, especially as you have already declared draw as virtual.